# Python: Sort items of two values (one must overlap; the other must not) into four bins

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, I am thinking my way through this problem as I write out the question. Each semester I need to find a way to sort 5-20 tests being given to 5-20 students into four available days we have for giving tests. My job is to try to pack all the tests of the same kind into a single day, if possible, while also making sure that no student is assigned to take two tests on the same day.

The list I get looks like this, where S is a student and T is the test they wish to take:

```
S1:T1
S1:T2
S2:T1
S2:T3
S2:T4
S3:T1
S3:T2
S4:T3
S5:T2
S5:T3
etc.
```

What I want to be able to do is sort all T2 onto a given day -- A, B, C, D -- and to make sure that a student, like S5 above -- isn't also taking another test that day.

I know this is a common enough problem that there are extant solutions from which I could model my own, but I don't know how to call it ... and so I have no search fu.

I know I can put these values into a dictionary, and I know I can sort by key or value, but I don't know how to consolidate one value and then distribute the other, such that `T1` and `T4` are given on Day A, and `T2` is given on Day B.

I know a query should have sample code -- e.g., sorting a dictionary by a key or value -- but I have no clue what to do next.

Comment: I had trouble understanding how both these answers were importing the data, so I ended up creating a list of tuples `[("S1", "4"), ("S1", "6"), ("S2", "11sf"), ("S3", "6"), ("S3", "12"), ("S3", "7"), ("S4", "11cws"), ("S5", "7"), ("S6", "4"), ("S6", "2"), ("S6", "11nf"), ("S7", "7"), ("S8", "6"), ("S8", "10"), ("S9", "5"), ("S10", "3"), ("S11", "11sl"), ("S12", "7"), ("S13", "11sl"), ("S14", "6")]` that I then imported as `students, tests = zip(*l_of_t)`. My notes on the outcomes of each answer are below.

Comment: I want to thank both bnaecker and Alex -- SO will only allow one "@" so I left both off -- for answers that got me facing in the right direction on a question I literally had no idea what to call nor where to start. Thanks for making SO great.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to determine is which tests have *disjoint sets* of students taking them. That is, given a set of tests, consider that set *valid* if the intersection of the sets of students taking each of them is empty.

Start by parsing the list you have into `students` and `tests`.

```
students, tests = zip(*map(lambda each: each.split(':'), data.split()))
```

Here, `data` is the list you've posted, newline- or whitespace-delimited. Next let's get the set of tests, and create a mapping from those tests to the students taking each of them.

```
unique_tests = set(tests)
test_map = {test : set() for test in unique_tests}
for student, test in zip(students, tests):
    test_map[test].add(student)
```

Now, `test_map` looks like so:

```
{'T1': {'S1', 'S2', 'S3'},
'T2': {'S1', 'S3', 'S5'},
'T3': {'S2', 'S4', 'S5'},
'T4': {'S2'}}
```

Next, let's enumerate the possible combinations of tests.

```
import itertools
test_combos = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        (itertools.combinations(unique_tests, i) for i in
        range(2, len(unique_tests) + 1))))
```

`test_combos` is:

```
[('T4', 'T3'),
('T4', 'T1'),
('T4', 'T2'),
('T3', 'T1'),
('T3', 'T2'),
('T1', 'T2'),
('T4', 'T3', 'T1'),
('T4', 'T3', 'T2'),
('T4', 'T1', 'T2'),
('T3', 'T1', 'T2'),
('T4', 'T3', 'T1', 'T2')]
```

Note that I'm omitting length-1 combinations, as with 4 tests you can always just place them on each of the 4 separate days. I'm only considering the case where you may need to join tests, i.e., you have more tests than days. (Besides, a singleton of one test is always a "valid" combination.)

Now let's define a function which will take a list of tests, and return `True` if that combination of tests is valid. Again, *valid* means that the intersection of all students taking that set of tests is empty.

```
def valid_test_combo(tests):
    pairs = itertools.combinations(tests, 2)
    return all(map(lambda pair:
            test_map[pair[0]].isdisjoint(test_map[pair[1]]), pairs))
```

Then we can get the set of valid test combinations by filtering all combinations:

```
valid_combos = set(filter(valid_test_combo, test_combos))
{('T4', 'T2')}
```

With the constraints you've given, you can only combine tests `'T2'` and `'T4'`.

Finally, create a set of all of the tests that *can* be combined, and then compute the remaining tests:

```
combined_tests = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(valid_combos))
remaining_tests = unique_tests - combined_tests
days = list(valid_combos) + list(remaining_tests)
```

Now `days` describes how you should administer the tests over the available days:

```
[('T4', 'T2'), 'T3', 'T1']
```

Note:

If you're curious, this seems to be nearly identical to the classic [*set-covering problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) combinatorics problem, which is difficult to solve in general (NP-hard). This solution is only really practical given that you have a small number of tests, students, and days, so we can just enumerate all possible combinations of tests.

Comment: I am going to try to put this into my script tomorrow and I'll give it a check then. What I really dig about his answer is how carefully you explain everything. Thanks, especially, for the note at the end.

Comment: @JohnLaudun You're welcome. I'm looking this over again after seeing your comment, and there are a couple of problems. First, the `valid_test_combo` function is not correct, as it only verifies that each set is pairwise disjoint from the first, not that they're *all* disjoint from one another. The second is in the computation of `remaining_tests`. If a test makes a valid combination with more than one other test, this method will "double-count" it. I'll think about ways to fix these, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: This is a terrific answer, and very helpful in terms of helping me learn how to think things through, but it doesn't deliver very helpful output: it's a long string of test combinations with no indication of days nor students. (See comment on Alex's answer below.)

Comment: @JohnLaudun Glad it was at least sort of helpful. The way to parse the output of my method is just a list of tests delivered on each day. Since you know which students are taking each test, that's all you need. But as I mentioned in my previous comment, the last bit isn't quite right. It doesn't account for the case in which the `valid_test_combo` returns two valid combinations with the same test in each. You'd need to filter those out separately, which isn't too hard. If you're still planning to use some of this code, I can edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an algorithms expert, but this seems to work. Please suggest if you'll find a bug.
The idea is to create sorting sequence for every new entry based on number of tests for the day. In case student has test on that day, it will try to move test on next day. The only issue is that it is not balancing number of test-students for every day, so the last day has least students/exams. That can be fixed by tweaking sorting sequence.

```
import operator

class NotAssigned(Exception):
    pass

students_tests = ['S1:T1','S1:T2','S2:T2','S2:T12','S2:T3','S2:T4','S3:T1','S3:T2','S4:T2','S4:T3','S5:T2','S5:T3','S6:T5','S6:T7']
days = [1,2,3,4]
final_plan = []
st_tup = []#Splitted Students_Tests
for st in students_tests:
    st_tup.append(tuple(st.split(":")))
students,tests = zip(*st_tup)

for i in range(len(students)):
    if i > 0:
        success = False
        d,s,t = zip(*final_plan)
        t_stats = {}#Get count of specific test on each day
        #Generate sorting sequence
        if tests[i] not in t:
            sort = days
        else:
            for day in days:
                t_stats[day] = 0
            for k in range(len(t)):
                if t[k] == tests[i]:
                        t_stats[d[k]] += 1
            sort = sorted(t_stats.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        try:
            for day in t_stats:
                if tuple([day,tests[i]]) in list(zip(d,t)):#Test already has been assigned for this day
                    if tuple([day,students[i]]) not in list(zip(d,s)):#Student doesn't have test this day
                        final_plan.append([day,students[i],tests[i]])
                        success = True
                        break
            if success == False:
                for day in days:
                    if tuple([day,students[i]]) not in list(zip(d,s)):#Student doesn't have test this day
                        final_plan.append([day,students[i],tests[i]])
                        success = True
                        break
            if success == False:
                raise NotAssigned
        except NotAssigned:
            print("Couldn't find suitable day for student " + students[i] + " for test " + tests[i])
    else:
        final_plan.append(list([days[0],students[0],tests[0]]))

print (final_plan)
```

Comment: I have a harder time following this -- but that's on me as a noob -- but it does deliver something like the desired answer. Given the input above, this outputs a list of lists: `[(1, 'S1', '4'), [2, 'S1', '6'], [1, 'S2', '11sf'], [2, 'S3', '6'], [1, 'S3', '12'], [3, 'S3', '7'], [1, 'S4', '11cws'], [3, 'S5', '7'], [1, 'S6', '4'], [2, 'S6', '2'], [3, 'S6', '11nf'], [3, 'S7', '7'], [2, 'S8', '6'], [1, 'S8', '10'], [1, 'S9', '5'], [1, 'S10', '3'], [1, 'S11', '11sl'], [3, 'S12', '7'], [1, 'S13', '11sl'], [2, 'S14', '6']]`. I can imagine re-organizing to make the day-test combination the priority.

Comment: What's weird about this output is that the first item in the list is a tuple and everything else is a list.

Comment: Yeah, missed it. But result stays the same, except the type. Fixed.